# Функция вывода названия сайта в Wordpress

Tags: архитектура

В каком файле php и какой функцией выводится название сайта 
,которое мы можем редактировать в "настройка, свойства сайта" на cms Wordpress?

Comment: http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_title